# AVFoundation audio player only updates volume from the slider when player is stopped. I want the volume to update in real time as I drag the slider

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, avfoundation

**What I'm building:** an app where users can play different ambient noises at different volumes.

**The problem:** I want the volume to change automatically as I drag the slider. In its current state, it will only reflect changes to the volume if I stop the player and then play it again.

**Example of the problem:** I tap on a sound to play it (in this case, the sound of a campfire). It starts playing normally. I drag the volume slider to a different value to change the volume. This SHOULD change the volume of the sound I'm hearing, but there is no change in volume. I can only hear the sound with the new volume level if I tap the sound to turn it off, then tap it again to turn it back on. Only then does it reflect the new volume level.

**Where I think the problem is**: I believe the problem is inside of the function playCampFire(). This is where I inserted the volume functionality inside of the do{} statement. I think because the code is only executed whenever the playCampFire() function is executed, which only happens when the sound is tapped. I've tried putting the .volume in different parts of the file, instead of just having it in the playCampFire() function, but I haven't had luck with that.

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

var campFirePlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
var campFireIsTapped: Bool = false

struct CF_RowView: View {
    
    
    @State var SFname: String
    @State var nameOfSound: String
    @State var urlOfSound: String
    @State var slidervalue: Float
    
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: SFname)
                .frame(width: 20)
            

            // Button to turn the sound on or off
            Button(action: {
                campFireIsTapped.toggle()
                campFireIsTapped ? self.playCampFire() : self.stopCampFire()
            }) {
                Text(nameOfSound).frame(width: 150, alignment: .leading)
            }
            .padding(.leading, 10)
            .foregroundColor(Color.primary)
            Spacer()
            Slider(value: $slidervalue)
                .frame(width: 130, alignment: .trailing)
        }.frame(width:320)
    }
    
    // function to play the sound
    func playCampFire() {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: urlOfSound, withExtension: "aif")
        
        guard url != nil else {
            return
        }
        
        do {
            campFirePlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
            campFirePlayer?.play()
            campFirePlayer?.numberOfLoops = -1
            campFirePlayer.volume = slidervalue
        } catch {
            print("\(error)")
        }
    }
    
    // function to turn off the sound
    func stopCampFire() {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: urlOfSound, withExtension: "aif")
        
        guard url != nil else {
            return
        }
        
        do {
            campFirePlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
            campFirePlayer?.stop()
        } catch {
            print("\(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

and here is a screenshot of the preview...

[image: preview]

**Question**: Where should I put .volume in my code so that it updates automatically as soon as I drag the volume slider, without me having to stop the sound and play it again?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [onChange](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onchange(of:perform:)) to detect when the value is updated. Just update your code to say this:

```
var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: SFname)
                .frame(width: 20)
            

            // Button to turn the sound on or off
            Button(action: {
                campFireIsTapped.toggle()
                campFireIsTapped ? self.playCampFire() : self.stopCampFire()
            }) {
                Text(nameOfSound).frame(width: 150, alignment: .leading)
            }
            .padding(.leading, 10)
            .foregroundColor(Color.primary)
            Spacer()
            Slider(value: $slidervalue)
                .frame(width: 130, alignment: .trailing)
        }
        .frame(width:320)
        .onChange(of: self.slidervalue) { value in
            self.campFirePlayer.volume = value
        }
    }
```